# Gcc not linking after operating system distribution upgrade

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, ld

Right now I am having difficulties linking a project I am working on with gcc4.6 in ubuntu 11.10. Before the distribution upgrade everything linked fine and it still compiles/links on the other developers machines. In case it's relevant, I'm not trying to cross compile.

Currently the compile succeeds then the linking fails with the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot open crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot open crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot open crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mc] Error 1
```

Here's some info on what I am using:

```
$gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,go --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 

$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.13-20ubuntu5) 2.13
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

$ find /usr -name "crt1.o"
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/crt1.o
/usr/lib32/crt1.o
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib32/crt1.o
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/crt1.o
```

Is there some way to point ld in the directions of the crt1.o files?

Happy to post any other info as needed!

Comment: Have you tried to install/upgrade `libc6-dev`? [http://anaaman.blogspot.com/2006/01/crt1o-no-such-file-no-such-file-or.html](http://anaaman.blogspot.com/2006/01/crt1o-no-such-file-no-such-file-or.html)

Comment: @ks1322, yes I have that installed already.

Comment: It looks like all of these are in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ how do I tell the ld to link to those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue a long time ago but hopefully posting this helps someone out.
All of the requisite .o files were installed but the ppa version of gcc 4.6 I had installed was looking in the wrong place for them. Reinstalling all of the packages from the official repo's solved the problem.

Make sure you have access to the correct repositories then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-dev
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-4.6
```